# TextButton not opening Frame

Tags: lua, roblox

So I have a simple text button inside of a ScreenGui with the following lua code.

```
local Button = script.Parent
local Frame = script.Parent.Parent.Frame

function onClick()
    if Frame.Visible == false then
        Frame.Visible = true
    elseif Frame.Visible == true then
        Frame.Visible = false
    end
    end

Button.MouseButton1Click:Connect(onClick)
```

However, when I click on the button, the frame does not show up.

The frame is set to not be visible by default.

The button is set to active, visible and selectable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with a clean script changing the `Frame` to visible. To check if your syntax is correct. I.e.:

```
local Frame = script.Parent.Parent.Frame
Frame.Visible = true
```

If it still doesn't work, try removing the `elseif`. I've had issues with scripts before just not liking the `elseif` command. You can just put `else` and it will do exactly the same job.

Comment: I just tried the clean script, and no it didn't change it. What's wrong with my syntax then?

Comment: Ok, so maybe look at the names of the objects you've referenced. Is `Frame` definitely capitalised? (In the Roblox Explorer)

Comment: yeah, I even changed the name around in both to different variables and it still isn't working

Comment: Are there any errors in your console. Go to view >> console.

Comment: I also tried replacing `elseif` but that didn't work either

Comment: What type of script are you using, a local, global (normal script), module script ect...?

Comment: You are right Universal, I wasn't using the right script.

Comment: Great, hope you have some fun with this code. I'd' be grateful if you could mark this thread as answered :)

Answer (score 1):

If you add in `print("Testing")` right after the function starts:

```
function onClick()
    print("Testing")
    if Frame.Visible == false then
```

and then run the code to make sure your `onClick()` function is actually being called.

If the code it called it'll print "Testing" and if it doesn't print then you know your code was just never run.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit stupid. Upon posting this question, I attempted to do some more reaserach. I found out that it might be the type of script causing it, and it was. You need to use a localscript for things like these.

Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Just as a note, when you're doing logic like:

```
if button.Visible == true then button.Visible = false
```

You can simplify the code by writing

```
button.Visible = not button.Visible
```

I would answer the rest of the question, but you've already accepted one!